# guest to customer

Tags: customer, register

My main question is to convert guest to customer

Here is the case:
Assumption: a guest placed an order, he successfully paid for that, when he is on the success page then I want to ask him

Do you want to register

If yes please enter your password. Then he clicks create account

Now I want convert this guest to customer and assign the orders to his new customer id

Please let me know if there is an easy way than using plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According magento,there are 3 sales table where magento is save customer related

- `sales_flat_order`
- `sales_flat_order_address`
- `sales_flat_order_grid`

### sales_flat_order table

**customer_id:** here `customer id save`.for `guest user` it `save as NULL`.You need to `update this column by customer id`.

**customer_is_guest**: it `save as 1 when guest` is saved an order and it value `should be 0 when customer is register`.

**customer_group_id:** Need update customer group by customer group id .

### sales_flat_order_grid table

**customer_id:** here `customer id save`.for `guest user` it `save as NULL`.You need to `update this column by customer id`.

### sales_flat_order_address

**customer_address_id:** for `guest user` it value is Null. You need update by customer address id whenever try transfer order

**customer_id:** here `customer id save`.for `guest user` it `save as NULL`.You need to `update this column by customer id`.

**Code like:**

```
$CustomerId=5;
$customerAddId=20;
$custommergrop=3;
$orderIncrementId=$this->getLastOrderId();
$orderObject=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
$billingId    = $orderObject->getBillingAddress()->getId();
$shipping   = $orderObject->isVirtual() ? null : $orderObject->getShippingAddress();

$billingObjct=Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($billingId);
$billingObjct->setData('customer_id',$CustomerId);
$billingObjct->setData('customer_address_id',$customerAddId);
$billingObjct->save();

if($shipping){  
 $shippingAddressid=$orderObject->getShippingAddress()->getId();
$shippingAddressObject=Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($shippingAddressid);
$shippingAddressObject->setData('customer_id',$CustomerId);
$shippingAddressObject->setData('customer_address_id',$customerAddId);
$shippingAddressObject->save();
}

$orderObject->setData('customer_id',$CustomerId);
$orderObject->setData('customer_is_guest',NULL); /*if null not work then try 0  instead of NULL*/
$orderObject->setData('customer_group_id',$custommergrop);
$orderObject->save();
```

Comment: Hi Amit , thanks almost done , one thing i didnt understand id customer_address_id, where would i get this

Comment: If customer have address in his/her  account dashboard..... you need put customer address id.

Comment: Hi Amit , as i am converting guest to customer , there is no address linked to his account , so how can i get customer_address_id .. (bit urgent , i need to fix asap ..)