# assign guest customer address to register customer

Tags: customer, magento-1, address

**Scenario**:
A user placed an order as guest, next time when he placing an order he  is registering as customer.

I managed to manually assign his old orders to new registered account based on his email address

Now  **my question is**:
How can I assign the old addresses to his new account?

If any of you have done that previously, please give any pointers to achieve this. Please, feel free to provide other better alternatives, if my thoughts are wrong somewhere. I'll greatly appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please update your question with information on how and when (which events, controllers, etc...) you have added code to assign the old orders to the new account? Maybe someone knows how to add code there for the addresses...

Comment: Hi , i am using onepagecheckout , when the user clicks on checkout , i am checking for his email in sales_flat_order for orders , assigning them to new customer account and updating guest customer status to 'NO'

Comment: So you're doing this manually?

Comment: yes , i am because magento don't do that automatically

Comment: please look on that http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62479/guest-to-customer/62481#62481

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $_orderEmail);

$i = 1;
foreach ($orders as $sorder) {
    $bAddress = $sorder->getBillingAddress();
    $bAddressData = $bAddress->getData();
    $cbAddress = Mage::getModel("customer/address");
    $cbAddress->setData($bAddressData);
    $cbAddress->setCustomerId($custId)
        ->setFirstname($bAddress->getFirstname())
        ->setMiddleName($bAddress->getMiddlename())
        ->setLastname($bAddress->getLastname())
        ->setRegion($bAddress->getRegion())
        ->setRegionId($bAddress->getRegionId())
        ->setPostcode($bAddress->getPostcode())
        ->setPostalcodeId($bAddress->getPostalcodeId())
        ->setStreet($bAddress->getStreet())
        ->setStreetnumber($bAddress->getStreetnumber())
        ->setCity($bAddress->getCity())
        ->setTelephone($bAddress->getTelephone())
        ->setCell($bAddress->getCell())
        ->setCountryId($bAddress->getCountryId())
        ->setAddressType($bAddress->getAddressType())
        ->setPrefix($bAddress->getPrefix())
        ->setSuffix($bAddress->getSuffix())
        ->setCompany($bAddress->getCompany())
        ->setGiftegistryItemId($bAddress->getGiftegistryItemId())
        ->setVatId($bAddress->getVatId())
        ->setVatIsValid($bAddress->getVatIsValid())
        ->setVatRequestId($bAddress->getVatRequestId())
        ->setVatRequestDate($bAddress->getVatRequestDate())
        ->setVatRequestSuccess($bAddress->getVatRequestSuccess())
        ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
        ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
    $cbAddress->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Old user is registered user

You should search the table `customer_entity` by email address. Now write down the old `entity_id` and the new `entity_id` (= *'customer ID'*).

Go to the table `customer_address_entity` and search for the old *'customer ID'* you've written down in the column **`parent_id`**. Now edit the records found and change the `parent_id` from the old *'customer ID'* to the new one.

#### Old user was a guest

If the old account was a guest checkout, then you'll need to get the address data from `sales_flat_order_address` and put it into the `customer_address_entity*` tables.

You could do this by running this SQL:

```
SET @orderID=123; /* The order's `entity_id` */
SET @custID=123; /* Your new `customer_entity`'s `entity_id` */

/* Start with billing address: */
INSERT INTO `customer_address_entity` (`entity_type_id`, `parent_id`) VALUES (2, @custID);
SET @addrID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO `customer_address_entity_int` (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) SELECT 2, 29, @addrID, `region_id` FROM `sales_flat_order_address` WHERE `parent_id` = @orderID AND `address_type` = 'billing';
INSERT INTO `customer_address_entity_text` (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) SELECT 2, 25, @addrID, `street` FROM `sales_flat_order_address` WHERE `parent_id` = @orderID AND `address_type` = 'billing';
```

You can repeat this for shipping address by replacing `'billing'` for `'shipping'` in the `WHERE` clause.

The new customer already has a default billing and shipping address set, but you can replace them with the ones from the guest by (for billing):

```
REPLACE INTO `customer_entity_int` SET `value` = @addrID WHERE `entity_type_id` = 1 AND `attribute_id` = 13 AND `customer_id` = @custID;
```

Repeat this for shipping address with ```attribute_id` = 14``.

You could also add more attributes to be added (see `` SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `entity_type_id` = 2 ``, for example *company*, *middlename*, *fax*, *suffix*, etc...)

Comment: there is no record in customer_entity if the user placed an order as guest

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: @Sree did this work out for you?