# How do I transfer my guest cart to a customer in Magento 2 REST API

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise

Luckily I am able to add items to guest a cart, but upon placing an order I want to guest to become a user and I am kind of confuse on how to transfer the former guest cart to the logged in user. I am using the Magento 2 rest API

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't fully understand you, but what I mean is how do I transfer the guest Cart to become the user cart when they signed in after adding some item in their cart as a guest.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62479/guest-to-customer

Comment: Have you figured out anything on this? I have got few on magento 1.x see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30455/how-to-copy-one-quote-only-cart-items-to-other-quote-only-items but not in M2. If you have figured out something please share